# How to call from Ibaction?

Tags: iphone

I am working on navigation based apps...i have shown first screen...in first there is a label,image,button and tab bar items...when we press a button ..it shows new screen..please tell me how to push a new screen

Answer (score 0):

> please tell me how to push a new
>   screen

Given that you are building a navigation-based app, the general pattern is:

```
- (void)showMyViewController
{
    MyViewController* myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
    [myViewController release];
}
```

Comment: -(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender{ secondViewcontroller=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewcontroller animated:YES]; } whenever i click on button it does nt show go to another view....n also button dose nt show any action..plzz help me out..